# Add-Member - ForEach Item Get Value From Other Info

Tags: windows, powershell, web

I have a PowerShell script, which contain this methods:
1. *Invoke-WebRequest*: to get my json file.
2. *Invoke-RestMethod*: to get all ip information from (1).

I want to `Add-Member` which from `$gip.city` to each `r.users` information

**Here is My Wrong Syntax:**

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://schoolfordesign.net/grabber.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$expip = $r.users  | select -expand ipaddress


ForEach($ips in $expip){

    $infoService = "http://ipinfo.io/$ips/json"
    $gip = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI $infoService

    $r.users| Add-Member -NotePropertyName city -NotePropertyValue $gip.city -Force
}

#Resilt:
$r.users
```

When I run it, the new member 'City' is not contain any value, it shows this result: 
[image: pic]

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, for each user add a city in $gip

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you. but still get error for me. I don't know. simply the $gip has many collection, such as (city, ip, location..etc), I want to grab City from it to my collection which is $r.users, please see the ,my post link photo.

Comment: @jessehouwing What's up with the LINQ-style scriptblocks? `$user => $user.ipaddress ...`? `=>` is not a PowerShell-operator AFAIK :-)

Comment: Yeah I was confused. See the actual answer for the proper syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial JSON from `http://schoolfordesign.net/grabber.json` contains user records like this:

```
{
    "ipaddress": "66.249.93.218",
    "date": "2017\/02\/23",
    "time": "07:03:34pm",
    "device": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ......."
}
```

The easiest solution is to iterate by each of these records as a whole, not just the IPs:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://schoolfordesign.net/grabber.json | ConvertFrom-Json

ForEach ($user in $r.users) {
    $info = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI "http://ipinfo.io/$($user.ipaddress)/json"
    $user | Add-Member city $info.city -force
}

$r.users
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said before, you need to look up the correct item in the `$users` collection to attach the city to:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://schoolfordesign.net/grabber.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$expip = $r.users  | select -expand ipaddress


ForEach($ips in $expip){

    $infoService = "http://ipinfo.io/$ips/json"
    $gip = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -URI $infoService
    $r.users| ?{ $_.ipaddress -eq $ips } | %{ Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName city -NotePropertyValue $gip.city -Force }
}

#Result:
$r.users
```

Or iterate over the users individually as suggested in the comments originally and nicely expanded by @wOxxOm

Which results in, (note that some IP records do not return City information):

```
ipaddress : 66.249.93.218
date      : 2017/02/23
time      : 07:03:34pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
city      : 

ipaddress : 66.249.93.219
date      : 2017/02/23
time      : 11:18:38pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
city      : 

ipaddress : 95.84.129.28
date      : 2017/02/24
time      : 08:56:23am
device    : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.5072
city      : Presnenskiy

ipaddress : 37.204.200.135
date      : 2017/02/24
time      : 12:59:51pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0)
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 66.249.93.217
date      : 2017/02/24
time      : 03:13:06pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
city      : 

ipaddress : 46.242.121.90
date      : 2017/02/24
time      : 08:27:51pm
device    : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.450
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 89.179.106.75
date      : 2017/02/24
time      : 09:15:15pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.3
city      : Rostov-on-Don

ipaddress : 176.193.111.146
date      : 2017/02/25
time      : 11:25:49am
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 37.204.142.237
date      : 2017/02/25
time      : 05:49:15pm
device    : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.5072
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 5.228.95.51
date      : 2017/02/25
time      : 07:47:42pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0)
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 109.63.236.189
date      : 2017/02/25
time      : 11:40:26pm
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.3
city      : Moscow

ipaddress : 176.195.116.125
date      : 2017/02/26
time      : 12:12:28am
device    : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.450
city      : Andreyevka

ipaddress : 66.249.93.218
date      : 2017/02/26
time      : 04:05:01am
device    : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87
city      :
```